# How to get a permanent user token for writes using the Trello API?

Tags: trello

I'm trying to write an app that updates my Trello cards with the API. How do I get a permanent user token for the app to write to my Trello board?

Thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do this in one of 2 ways -

Direct the user to the below address. This will direct the user to a page that has a token that she can copy and paste back to you. The important bit is that you ask for `expiration = never` and `scope = read,write`

```
https://trello.com/1/authorize?key=substitutewithyourapplicationkey&scope=read%2Cwrite&name=My+Application&expiration=never&response_type=token
```

Or use OAuth (harder) to automate the request for an access token. Read more in the [documentation](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/index.html#getting-a-token-from-a-user).

Once you have the token, you can make any API call you'd like.

Comment: link to the docs page: https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/index.html#getting-a-token-from-a-user

Answer (score 11):

If you have to do everything server-side, Andy Jones is correct, those are the only two ways.

It should be noted, however, that if you can write javascript+jquery code rather than having to do the redirections server-side, you can take advantage of Trello's client.js wrapper, which does exactly what Andy described, but takes care of most of it for you, which is way convenient.

And, as I recently discovered, if you do need to do processing server-side, you can still probably use client.js, then just get the token with Trello.token() in your auth success handler, and pass that to your server-side code. It looks like this:

```
// include whatever version of jquery you want to use first
<script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=[your application key]" type="text/javascript"></script>

// call this whenever you want to make sure Trello is authenticated, and get a key. 
// I don't call it until the user needs to push something to Trello,
// but you could call it in document.ready if that made more sense in your case.
function AuthenticateTrello() {
        Trello.authorize({
            name: "your project name",
            type: "popup",
            interactive: true,
            expiration: "never",
            success: function () { onAuthorizeSuccessful(); },
            error: function () { onFailedAuthorization(); },
            scope: { write: true, read: true },
        });
 }

function onAuthorizeSuccessful() {
    var token = Trello.token();
    // whatever you want to do with your token. 
    // if you can do everything client-side, there are other wrapper functions
    // so you never need to use the token directly if you don't want to.
}

function onFailedAuthorization() {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: This is very very helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a token for personal use you can get `app-key`, `secret` and `token` based on you being logged in over [here](https://trello.com/app-key).