# Just getting started with Manatee.trello and encountering the following error

Tags: manatee.trello

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException' in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll

```
Dim serializer As New ManateeSerializer

TrelloConfiguration.Serializer = serializer
TrelloConfiguration.Deserializer = serializer
TrelloConfiguration.JsonFactory = New ManateeFactory()
TrelloConfiguration.RestClientProvider = New WebApiClientProvider()
TrelloAuthorization.Default.AppKey = "[My app key]"
TrelloAuthorization.Default.UserToken = "[my app secret]"

Dim boardId As String = "56425ef7de9eb12872b4a662"
Dim Board As New Board(boardId)
Console.WriteLine(Board)
```

This is my first step off into accessing Trello via the API so I'm sure I must be missing something important.  App compiles fine, and as long as I don't reference the "Board" code executes with no errors.

I'm not real clear what the "boardId" should be?  Got it of the JSON example from a card from the Trello API web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by including the following:

```
TrelloConfiguration.RestClientProvider = New RestSharpClientProvider()
```

It seems this line of code was missing in the example I copied.

Also for any newbies that end up finding this, my next question was how do I get a user token for use with the API.  This answer got me going...

[How to get a permanent user token for writes using the Trello API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178907/how-to-get-a-permanent-user-token-for-writes-using-the-trello-api)

Comment: Thanks for using Manatee.Trello.  I think the problem was that you don't have a token.  In those cases, Trello replies with either plain text or HTML.

Comment: Regarding the token question.  See [their docs](http://developers.trello.com/authorize).